# What are the various methods for parsing a file in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I am currently working on parsing a text file. I need to extract a keyword from a particular line in the file. I want to know the various methods on how to parse a file.

As of now, I am parsing the file line by line and splitting the line and the required keyword. In case of file containing million lines, it would take time to process it and find the word. I need an alternate parsing methodology

```
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(parsed));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("Exception:") || line.contains("exception")) {
            String linemap = line;
            parsedLine = linemap.split("REASON:");
         }
     }
```

The above code, checks each line for the keyword Exception, and stores the content after "REASON:" in the String parsed. Kindly suggest alternate and better methods, if available (other than line by line parsing) to parse the above content.

Comment: In what way does your current solution not meet your needs? There are an unlimited number of ways to approach this problem, but unless you can give some criteria for what a satisfactory method would achieve, this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: I think you simply should avoid a processing twice the lines without errors: your code check first "Exception:" then "exception" so 2 check for every line. You can check once just the keyword "ception"

Comment: @mypetlion The current approach does satisfy the intended purpose. I just wanted to know if a few other methods other than line by line parsing.I couldn't find much information hence my question :) I hope you can give me a selective few approaches.

Comment: @ivan.rosina Sure. Thank you for pointing out that, will make the change.